# ggplot Adding Tracking Colors Below X-Axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add a line below the x-axis where its color is dependant on a factor that is not plotted.

In this example, I'm creating a box plot and would like to add a line that indicates another variable.

Using the cars data set as an example and then physically dawing in what I'm trying to do:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

My thought was to create a bar, column, or geom_tile plot and then arrange it below the boxplot. This is how I would do it in base R. Is there a way to add in these kinds of color labels in ggplot2?

Comment: How are you deciding the grouping along the x-axis?

Comment: @camille it would be another factor column in the dataset - such as "carb" in mtcars. It does not make much sense in this dataset, but in the data I have, there are a lot of different factors (many binary) that I want to see their presence or absence given the x variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The natural way in `ggplot2` to do this sort of thing would to be facet on the categorical variable to create subplots. However if you want to keep everything on the same graph you could try using a `geom_tile()` layer something like this:

```
df <-data.frame(x = factor(c(4,6,8)), colour = factor(c(1,2,1)))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot()  +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x = x, y = 8, fill = colour))
```

[image]

Alternatively as you suggest you could align an additional plot underneath it. You could use `ggarrange()` in the `ggpubr` package for this:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot()  +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x = x, y = 10, fill = colour))
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=1, fill = colour)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('orange', 'green', 'orange')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(plot1, plot2, nrow = 2, heights = c(10, 1), align = 'h')
```

[image]