# How can I add a line below axis labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r

How can I add a line below axis labels just like in the attached picture where there is a line below 50,100 and 200 axis labels?
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot is one way to go, but using `segmentsGrob` & `textGrob`s but these things are a bit more esily done in base r as in meW answer

Answer (score 1):

An example **(doesn't contain GGPLOT2)**:

```
data("mtcars")
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", 
        xlab="Number of Gears")
axis(1, # Put 1 for X-axis, 2 for Y-axis
     at=c(0, 5), #Limit of line
     col="red", 
     line=2.5, # how much gap you need between line and X-axis
     labels=rep("",2), # remove line labels
     lwd=2,
     lwd.ticks=0) # remove ticks
```

[image: plt]

Multiple lines, just append another `axis` command as -

```
data("mtcars")
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", 
        xlab="Number of Gears")
axis(1, # Put 1 for X-axis, 2 for Y-axis
     at=c(0, 2.5), #Limit of line
     col="red", 
     line=2.5, # how much gap you need between line and X-axis
     labels=rep("",2), # remove line labels
     lwd=2,
     lwd.ticks=0) # remove ticks

axis(1, # Put 1 for X-axis, 2 for Y-axis
     at=3+c(0, 2.5), #Limit of line
     col="blue", 
     line=2.5, # how much gap you need between line and X-axis
     labels=rep("",2), # remove line labels
     lwd=2,
     lwd.ticks=0) # remove ticks
```

[image: plt2]

Comment: I get this error: Error in axis(1, at = c(0, 5), col = "red", line = 2.5, labels = rep("",  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: you need to call the plot command, which means plot the figure first then draw the line

Comment: If following is my data frame, how can I add the line?                                                                                                                         
 conc <- c("0","50","100","200")
values <- c(40.83,2.16,8.16,18.66,30.16)                       
 df <- data.frame(conc,values)                                                                   
ggplot(df, aes(x = conc,y = values, fill = conc))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity",show.legend = FALSE )

Comment: What do you mean by these variables? Elaborate.

Comment: If following is my data frame, how can I add the line?                                      
conc <- c("0","50","100","200")                                                                       
values <- c(40.83,2.16,8.16,18.66,30.16)                                                              df <- data.frame(conc,values) ggplot(df, aes(x = conc,y = values, fill = conc))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity",show.legend = FALSE )

Comment: you have error while forming dataframe. Provide equal number of values in both columns and also provide limit of line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186043/discussion-between-m-r-wani-and-mew).

Comment: df <- data.frame(conc = c(0,50,100,150), 
values = c(2,8,18,30)) 
df$conc <- as.factor(df$conc) 
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=conc,y=values,fill = conc))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",show.legend = FALSE) 
How to add a line below x-axis labels from 0 to 100 and write "conc in mg" below that line

Comment: for ggplot2 refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848658/ggplot-adding-tracking-colors-below-x-axis

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `facet_wrap` from `ggplot2` is a starting point:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(hp_200 = ifelse(hp > 200, "hp > 200", "hp <= 200")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hp)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 20) +
  facet_wrap(~ hp_200, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  ggthemes::theme_hc()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>